# Javascript Inheritance using constructor functions

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm trying to make one constructor function parent of another constructor function.

```
function Fruit() {
    this.isEatable = function() {
        return eatable;
    };
}
function Apple(eatable , sweet) {
    this.isSweet = function() {
        return sweet;
    };
    var instance = {};
    Fruit.apply(instance);
    _.extend(this, instance);
}

var a = new Apple(true, false);

console.log(a.isEatable()); // Uncaught ReferenceError: eatable is not defined
```

But as you can see I get an error , what is the reason ? What is the better way to make one function inherit from another function ?

I also tried the following , and I still get the same error :

```
function Fruit() {
    this.isEatable = function() {
        return eatable;
    };
}
function Apple(eatable , sweet) {
    this.isSweet = function() {
        return sweet;
    };
}

_.extend(Apple.prototype , Fruit.prototype);// I use lodash library
var a = new Apple(true, false);

console.log(a.isEatable()); // Uncaught ReferenceError: eatable is not defined
```

Comment: How would you expect `new Fruit().isEatable()` to work?

Comment: JavaScript has only lexical scope for variables. [Use properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572?javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object)!

Comment: @Bergi : I don't expect it to work. I expect `instance` to have it after calling `apply`

Comment: Yes, `instance` *does* have the `isEatable` method after you called `apply`, but the method does not have an `eatable` variable in its scope - which is where it is declared, not where it is used. For that, you have to use `this.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
function Fruit(eatable) {
    this.eatable = eatable;
    this.isEatable = function() {
        return this.eatable;
    };
}

function Apple(eatable , sweet) {
    // Call the constructor of the inherited 'object'
    Fruit.call(this, eatable);

    this.sweet = sweet;

    this.isSweet = function() {
        return this.sweet;
    };
}

// Inherit the Fruit.prototype methods for Apple
Apple.prototype = Object.create(Fruit.prototype);

var a = new Apple(true, false);

console.log(a.isEatable());
```

This is based off the (Very useful) code given as an example in the [MDN Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) documentation. Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/782jn1gu/).

Comment: If you remove the line at which you do 'Object.create' it still works. right ?

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh: But then `a instanceof Fruit` no longer works. Also, if you had put the methods on the prototype, like `Fruit.prototype.isEatable() { return this.eatable; };` (which in fact you should consider to do), it would no longer work without `Object.create` inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

just other way

```
function Fruit() {
    this.isEatable = function() {
        return this.eatable;
    };
}
function Apple(eatable , sweet) {
    this.sweet=sweet;
    this.eatable=eatable;
    this.isSweet = function() {
        return this.sweet;
    };
    this.prototype= Fruit.apply(this);
}

var a = new Apple(true, false);

console.log(a.isEatable());
```

It's somewhat same thing as @Asryael i guess

short explanation: prototype binds new Fruit object with `this` of Apple , so you don't need to pass parameters again in root object, `this` takes care of it .

Comment: I don't want to change the prototype of this, because later if someone decides to extend the definition of `Apple` it won't affect the instances. right ?

Comment: can u give an example of "extend the definition" ? 
i mean if u add new params to apple , it won't affect.

Comment: `this.prototype= Fruit.apply(this);` is really really not going to work.

Comment: @Bergi care to explain ? nd ya thanks for the downvote

Comment: Apple's prototype is a new Fruit object, Fruit object binded to that Apple Object. Whats wrong in this ? Is it bcoz Fruit cannot exist without Apple , as it doesn't have a eatable param